# MailKit From Address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mailkit

Im using mailKit in asp mvc core to collect email from a IMAP mailbox.

I return the message using the command

```
var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid)
```

This returns all the results of the message. From here i want to access the sender email address (not including the name). After breakpointing on the above line i can see that the variable message has the following property

```
message
-From
--From(Array)
---From(item)
----Name (name of the sender)
----Address(email of the sender)
```

When referencing the above above using the message i am able to receive the name, however the address is not listed (within intelisence, nor will it build)

```
var name = message.From[0].Name.ToString()
```

Does anyone know why this would be visible as properties of the variable but not accessible via the code?

i simply want to

```
var name = message.From[0].Name.ToString()
```

Comment: Does `GetMessage` return a dynamic object? Do you get an error when you try this code? Is the property `Name` of type `string`?

Comment: no error, its  just not available when typing in visual studio. But does show ehn i breakpoint and examine the message variable

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `MimeMessage.From` property is a `InternetAddressList` (more-or-less `List<InternetAddress>`).

`InternetAddress` is an abstract base class for `MailboxAddress` and `GroupAddress` which only contains a `Name` property as you've discovered.

In order to get the `Address`, you first need to cast it to a `MailboxAddress`... but only if it is actually a `MailboxAddress` or you'll get a cast exception.

`InternetAddressList` has a convenience property called `Mailboxes` which can be used to iterate over a flattened list of the `MailboxAddress`es contained within.

Comment: var EmailAddress = Message.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault().Address;

Comment: More information regarding this matter can be found in the [MailKit FAQ](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Frequently-Asked-Questions.htm#AddressHeaders).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
message.From.Mailboxes.Single().Address;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code block.

`message.From.OfType<MailboxAddress>().Single().Address;`